# Find the last Row in dataframe from a large set of values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

A  B
a  4  q
a  8  q
a  9  q
a  8  q
a  3  q
a  46  q
a  45  q
a  1  q
b  9  w
b  5  wi
b  4  w
b  7  w
b  8  w

Final Output

a  1  q
b  8  w

Comment: @jezrael pls see this

Comment: Use `df = df.drop_duplicates('A', keep='last')`